On Ubuntu 24.10 my ethernet control is shown as unclaimed using lshw -C network
output from:
lshw -C Network

 *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c39000-f7c39fff ioport:f080(size=32)

On Window 10 the network is shown as Stopped, but I can disable then enable and the connection works until I restart system.
The problem also happened with 22.04
Output from
dmesg | grep -e e100
 [    0.670774] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver  
 [    0.671469] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.   
 [    0.674944] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode  
 [    1.696074] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3  

Output from
sudo ./bootutil64e
Error: Connection to QV driver failed - please reinstall it!  

Intel(R) Ethernet Flash Firmware Utility  
BootUtil version 1.42.06.0  
Copyright (C) 2003-2024 Intel Corporation  

Type BootUtil -? for help  

Port Network Address Location Series  WOL Flash Firmware   Version  
==== =============== ======== ======= ==== ========================= =======  
  1   3417EBAAF1BE     0:25.0 Gigabit N/A FLASH Not Present  

Output from
lspci -nnk
 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
  DeviceName:  Onboard LAN  
  Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [1028:052c]  
  Kernel modules: e1000e  

Output from
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 6.8.0-47-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 21:40:26 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
The additional information provided "probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3" and "Connection to QV driver failed" that I didn't see in any of the other questions. On the same hardware I have been able to update driver in Windows 10 and the problem is fixed.  I have been unable to update driver in Ubuntu 22.04.  I am new to Ubuntu/Linux and need all the help I can get.

This question is similar to: e1000e error -5 and UNCLAIMED network interface after installing ubuntu newly. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
